# Why is there no з- prefix in Russian?

Tags: орфография, приставки

All the other prefixes ending in **с** I can think of off the top of my head have a counterpart ending with **з**.

> бес-/без-
>
> ис-/из-
>
> вос-/воз-

The version with **с** is used before voiceless consonants, and the version with **з** is used before vowels and voiced consonants.

> бесполезный, безымянный, бездушный
>
> исходить, изыди, изгой
>
> воспевать, возобновить, возможно

But the **с-** prefix is used in all cases, although before voiced consonants it is often pronounced as **/z/**

> сделать, сброд, сглаживание

Is there a linguistic or historical reason why this prefix seems to stand as an exception?

Comment: There are several words in Russian that start with **зд**, however in those cases **з-** is not a prefix but rather part of the root: _здание, здесь, здоровье_

Comment: Historically, `з` in `здоровье` was a prefix `съ-` of another origin, not related to `cѫ` and meaning "good". Proto-Slavic `*съдорвъ` literally meant "of good wood", `*съмьрть` — "good (natural) death".

Comment: This could be a good question on [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) too.

Comment: @Alenanno: Would it? Wouldn't it be too specific to Russian to be on-topic in Linguistics.SE?

Comment: Uhm, naah, it wouldn't. We allow single language questions (as long as they are Linguistics in nature)... the answers can still expand on other languages anyway (if related). :)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan In any case, I suppose you have to leave this here or (if you want) ask for migration. Don't cross post. See the [FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/176533).

Comment: @Alenanno: Hmm.. Ok, I'll take that into consideration. However, it's also a good fit here, and it has an awesome answer by Quassnoi, so migrating it makes no sense IMO

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I wasn't suggesting in migrating it, just letting you know the possibilities. :P

Comment: @Alenanno: I wonder if I ask a question specific to Armenian (linguistic in nature) on Linguistics.SE, would it be answered? :D :D :D

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Sure!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefixes in Slavic languages originated from the prepositions merged with the roots.

The old Slavic prepositions `надъ`, `подъ` etc. which ended with `ъ`, were merged before the fall of the reduced vowels so the vowel was kept, and you can still see it on its historical place before the roots starting with a yotized vowel: *объятие*.

When the reduced vowels fell, prononciation changed to agree the articulation of now adjacent consonants, but orthography did not reflect it. The words *по**дът**вердити*, *о**тъд**авити* (`ъ` was read as a really short `ы`) became *по**дт**вердить*, *о**тд**авить* etc, with impossible combinations of a voiced and voiceless consonant. The both consontants are now voiced or not according to the last one (*[поттвердить], [оддавить]*) but written the old way.

The prepositions ending in `-с` and `-з` (`раз`, `из` etc.), however, did not end with a vowel. The orthography reflected it from the beginning.

But the prefix `с-` originated from the preposition `cѫ` which never ended in `-с`. It ended with `ѫ`. This nasal sound after denasalization of the yuses had changed into `y` in nouns like `сумерки`, `сутки` and into `ъ` (which later fell) in verbs, and undergone the process described earlier. So this prefix does not change in writing, just as the prefixes not ending with `-c/з` don't.

The prepositions `без` and `через` (and the Church Slavonic borrowing `чрез`) merged much later than the others, so until the orthography reform of 1918, they were always written `без-`, `чрез-` and `через-`.

Comment: Just curious: of the non-native speakers, has anyone understood anything? :)

Comment: I did understand something. :-) I think in old Russian the symbols Ъ and ь indicated vowels that are not pronounced any more. This might have influenced the consonant preceding them. Maybe one could add that other prepositions end in з / с while the preposition с __starts__ with с. However, since I am not a native speaker, I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: @Giorgio: `ъ` has long since fallen, so the preposition `cъ` is now `с` which starts **and** ends with `c` :). Is it what you meant?

Comment: What I meant is that it always started with с and only more recently it also ends with с. If the changes in orthography occurred before the fall of Ъ this might have influenced how the preposition с is written. But this is just my own speculation. :-)

Comment: Until the orthography reform, `раз-` (`роз-`) and `из-` were always written with `з` too.

Comment: @thorn: So, did it use to be *разписывать*, *разкапывать*? Ew! :)

Comment: @thorn: only before `с` and voiced consonants: `разслѣдовать` but `расписывать`.

Comment: @Quassnoi Oh, indeed! When were there rules established?

Comment: @thorn: first codified by Grot in late `XIX` I believe.

Comment: @thorn: but gramotas of early `XII` (the end of the fall of the reduced) already omit `ъ` and put `с` before voiceless consonants. See `849`: http://gramoty.ru/index.php?act=full&id=868 (*створѧ*, *исправи*).